# How to track what initial traffic source caused an event

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

Events on my site (e.g. conversions and registrations) most of the time don't happen right away.  What I want to do is create a tracking script that allows the user to click a link and that link contains the traffic source.  If that link click eventually results in a conversion I want it attributed to the original link click, (not the most recent because that is usually Direct / None.

Something like
http://domain.com/?track=originalsource

I'm going to have affiliates and maybe I can give them google links to track which affiliates are generating conversions.

Or maybe there's some good software out there that can do something really good like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This article is from 2010 so it may need some modification to the implementation, but here's how it's done with Google Analytics:

http://www.distilled.net/blog/seo/first-touch-tracking-in-google-analytics/

Comment: Interesting Article, checking it out.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem a few years ago.  I set a cookie when a user came in on an affiliate link and when the user checked out, I would check to see if that cookie had been set.  It worked pretty well.

Comment: Hmm, that's a good idea